# click event is called only once even though i am writing it twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the above code, I am expecting the click event will happen twice but it happening only once. Please suggest any modification.

```
if ($("#profile-menu ul.myprfile-subheaderslicker li.myaccnt-navactive").index() == 3) {
    $(".slick-next").trigger("click");
    $(".slick-next").trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: Unable to replicate, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/yhyv9uxw/

Answer (score 1):

Try with double click in place of using two single clicks:

```
$(".slick-next").trigger("dblclick");
```

or:

```
$(".slick-next").dblclick();
```